# Getting error when calling method in AppDelegate from a button action.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, appdelegate

When I click "save" I am getting an error when it talks back to the AppDelegate.

I'm sure, that I'm missing something small here, but if anyone has a quick answer it would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
-[AppDelegate saveNewUsername:username:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e403d0
```

Here's my button action:

```
-(IBAction)saveButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSString *userid = [appDelegate retrieveFromUserDefaults:@"userid"];
NSMutableArray *currentUser = [appDelegate getUserInfo:userid];
NSString *currentUsername = [currentUser objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"%@", userid);

if ([currUsername.text isEqualToString:currentUsername]) {
    //here we'll check and make sure the new username is valid and doesn't already exist (for now just update local DB)
    if ([theNewUsername.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"You must enter something for your new username." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    } else {
        int returnVal = [appDelegate saveNewUsername:userid username:theNewUsername.text];
        if (returnVal == 1) {
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        } else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"There was an error saving to the database." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
} else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"The username you entered is not your current username." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
}
```

And here's my AppDelegate method:

```
-(int)saveNewUsername:(NSString *)user_id username:(NSString *)username
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"somedbname.sqlite3"];

FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:writableDBPath];

if (![db open]) {
    NSLog(@"Could not open db.");
    return 0;
} else {
    [db intForQuery:@"UPDATE user SET username=? WHERE user_id=?", username, user_id];

    if ([db hadError]) {
        NSLog(@"Error %d: %@", [db lastErrorCode], [db lastErrorMessage]);
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks OK. So I guess appDelegate is actually not an instance of AppDelegate.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Set a breakpoint there and have a look in the debugger to check whether it is indeed an instance of AppDelegate.

Comment: I thought of that, but it uses appDelegate to grab the stored userid right before it tries to save the new username (and works).  Which is why it has me so confused.

Comment: I cleaned my project, then rebuilt.  Works just fine.  Very odd.